# asynchronous serial port communication in windows in c

Tags: c, windows, asynchronous, serial-port

I am getting an error when I try to run a c file which does some basic writes to a serial port. I am trying to run it asynchronously because the writes sometimes take a long time to transfer. My original version had it running synchronously with WriteFile() commands which worked fine. I am new to using OVERLAPPED and would appreciate and input concerning it.

The error I am getting is:

```
Debug Assertion Failed! 
<path to dbgheap.c> 
Line: 1317 
Expression: _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)
```

when the second write function is called.

In main:

```
    {
        //initialized port (with overlapped), DBC, and timeouts

        result = write_port(outPortHandle, 128);
        result = write_port(outPortHandle, 131);
    }




static void CALLBACK write_compl(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped) {
        //write completed. check for errors? if so throw an exception maybe?
        printf("write completed--and made it to callback function\n");
    }


int write_port(HANDLE hComm,BYTE* lpBuf) {

   OVERLAPPED osWrite = {0};

   // Create this write operation's OVERLAPPED structure's hEvent.
   osWrite.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
   if (osWrite.hEvent == NULL)
      // error creating overlapped event handle
      return 0;

   // Issue write.
   if (!WriteFileEx(hComm, &lpBuf, 1, &osWrite, &write_compl )) {
      if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) { 
         // WriteFile failed, but isn't delayed. Report error and abort.
          printf("last error: %ld",GetLastError());
          return 0; //failed, return false;
      }
      else {
         // Write is pending.
         WaitForSingleObjectEx(osWrite.hEvent, 50, TRUE);   //50 ms timeout

        return -1; //pending
      }
   }
   else {
        return 1; //finished
   }
}
```

---

That was not the full code, sorry. I was using an array of BYTEs as well, not constants. But system("pause")'s were causing my debug assertion failed errors, and after carefully looking through my code, when the WriteFileEx() was successful, it was never setting an alert/timeout on the event in the overlapped structure, so the callback function would never get called. I fixed these problems though.

I just need help with the handling/accessing a single BYTE in a structure which is allocated when a ReadFileEx() function is called (for storing the BYTE that is read so it can be handled). I need to know how to access that BYTE storage using an offset and make the overlapped structure null. Would making the overlapped structure null be as simple as setting the handle in it to INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE?

Comment: You are using constants (128, 131) as pointers to a byte array. Have you copied the source correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple of issues:

---

You are passing an integer as a pointer (your compiler should warn against this or preferably refuse to compile the code):

> result = write_port(outPortHandle, 128);

Compare this to the definition of write_port:

> int write_port(HANDLE hComm,BYTE* lpBuf) {

The above statements doesn't match. Later on you then pass a pointer to the lpBuf pointer to the WriteFileEx function by taking the address of the BYTE* -> "&lpBuf". This will not result in what you think it will do.

---

Even if you fix this, you will still have potential lifetime issues whenever the write is successfully queued but won't complete within the 50 ms timeout.

When using overlapped I/O, you need to make sure that the read/write buffer and the overlapped structure remain valid until the I/O is completed, cancelled or the associated device is closed. In your code above you use a pointer to an OVERLAPPED struct that lives on the stack in your call to WriteFileEx. If WriteFileEx does not complete within 50 ms, the pending I/O will have a reference to a non-existing OVERLAPPED struct and you will (hopefully) have an access violation (or worse, silently corrupted stack data somewhere in your app).

The canonical way of handling these lifetime issues (if performance is not a big issue), is to use a custom struct that includes an OVERLAPPED struct and some storage for the data to be read/written. Allocate the struct when posting the write and deallocate the struct from the I/O completion routine. Pass the address of the included OVERLAPPED struct to WriteFileEx, and use e.g. offsetof to get the address to the custom struct from the OVERLAPPED address in the completion routine.

Also note that WriteFileEx does not actually use the hEvent member, IIRC.

---

EDIT: Added code sample, please note:

1. I haven't actually tried to compile the code, there might be typos or other problems with the code.
2. It's not the most efficient way of sending data (allocating/deallocating a memory block for each byte that is sent). It should be easy to improve, though.

```
    #include <stddef.h>
    #include <assert.h>
    #include <windows.h>

    // ...
    typedef struct _MYOVERLAPPED
    {
        OVERLAPPED ol;
        BYTE buffer;
    } MYOVERLAPPED, *LPMYOVERLAPPED;
    // ...

    static void CALLBACK write_compl(DWORD dwErrorCode, DWORD dwNumberOfBytesTransfered, LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped)
    {
        if (NULL == lpOverlapped)
        {
            assert(!"Should never happen");
            return;
        }

        LPBYTE pOlAsBytes = (LPBYTE)lpOverlapped;
        LPBYTE pMyOlAsBytes = pOlAsBytes - offsetof(MYOVERLAPPED, ol);
        LPMYOVERLAPPED pMyOl = (LPMYOVERLAPPED)pOlAsBytes;

        if ((ERROR_SUCCESS == dwErrorCode) && 
            (sizeof(BYTE) == dwNumberOfBytesTransfered))
        {
            printf("written %uc\n", pMyOl->buffer);
        }
        else
        {
            // handle error
        }

        free(pMyOl);
    }


    int write_port(HANDLE hComm, BYTE byte) {

       LPMYOVERLAPPED pMyOl = (LPMYOVERLAPPED)malloc(sizeof(MYOVERLAPPED));

       ZeroMemory(pMyOl, sizeof(MYOVERLAPPED));
       pMyOl->buffer = byte;

       // Issue write.
       if (!WriteFileEx(hComm, &pMyOl->buffer, sizeof(BYTE), pMyOl, &write_compl )) {
          if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) { 
             // WriteFile failed, but isn't delayed. Report error and abort.
              free(pMyOl);
              printf("last error: %ld",GetLastError());
              return 0; //failed, return false;
          }
          else {
            return -1; //pending
          }
       }
       else {
            free(pMyOl);
            return 1; //finished
       }
    }
```

Comment: Could you possibly go into detail about how to use the offset in the overlapped structure to access a single BYTE which would be allocated as the buffer result of a ReadFileEx() command, so I can handle the BYTE from the completion function? I'm not too familiar with using offsets to access other data structures.
And also would there be any potential problems with having an INFINITE timeout on the WaitForSingleObjectEx()?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     result = write_port(outPortHandle, 128);
>     result = write_port(outPortHandle, 131);
> ```

The lpBuf argument have to be pointers to buffers, not constants.

e.g.

```
char buffer;
buffer = 128;
result = write_port(outPortHandle, &buffer);
buffer = 131;
result = write_port(outPortHandle, &buffer);
```

What you really want to do is also pass a buffer length.

e.g.

```
    char buffer[]  = { 128, 131 };
    result = write_port(outPortHandle, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));

int write_port(HANDLE hComm,BYTE* lpBuf, size_t length) {

   ...

   // Issue write.
   if (!WriteFileEx(hComm, &lpBuf, length, &osWrite, &write_compl )) {
   ...
```

Comment: Added a 'be' on that first sentence and a comma to clarify - but yeah, 128 is never a valid pointer.

Comment: I'm using single bytes in each write, so the size is always 1.